# New intent crashes application

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to start new activity after click on ListView item but application crashes. If I comment out intent initialization, and leave only toast message app doesn't crash. Сonsequently problem is in Intent. I have no ideas why that happens. Any help will be appreciated.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private ArrayList<Cinemas> cinema;
        private CinemasAdapter cinemaAdapter;
        private ListView list;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

            cinema = new Handler().handle(); 
            cinemaAdapter = new CinemasAdapter(this, R.layout.movie_data_row, cinema);
            list = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listing1);     
            list.setAdapter(cinemaAdapter);
            setContentView(list);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                Context context = null;
                Cinemas movie = cinemaAdapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent (context,More.class);
                startActivity(intent); 
            }
            });
        }    
    }
```

Here is logcat:

```
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at com.example.bakumovies.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:47)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-16 13:33:28.882: E/AndroidRuntime(2536):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have initialized the context with null

```
  Context context = null;

 Intent intent = new Intent (context,More.class);
```

And your are starting intent with the context, this causes `NullPointerException`

So do like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, More.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, More.class);
```

Instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent (context,More.class);
```

You were getting a `NullPointerException` because, well, you assigned `context` to `null`.